# Custom cell in UITableView is not displaying properly - only last cell is populated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Apologies if this comes across as a beginner's question. I'm trying to populate a UITableView with sections and custom cell formatting.

I've created a customCell in ViewControl.xib which sits along the main view and looks like this:
[customCell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ71A.png)

I have a dictionary to load up the values using a method in another class, depending on which row it's at. If it's in Row 1, load details for item 1 etc.

This is the code I'm using:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];

    // assigns current row's labels
    NSArray * customCellText = [Model cellText:indexPath.row];
    dinnerItem.text = customCellText[0];
    dinnerDescription.text = customCellText[1];
    dinnerTime.text = customCellText[2];

    cell = customCell;
    return cell;
}
```

And this is currently what's being generated:

[iPhone simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ71A.png#1)

The issues I have:

- It's not populating all rows, only the last one.
- I can only seem to click on the row which is populated, and even then
  it stays selected as opposed to 'clicking on it'.
- If I drag it up or down quickly it crashes.

I presume it has to do with the way it's redrawing/populating cells?

Thanks in advance!
SineTwo

**EDIT, ADDED MORE CODE FOR CLARIFICATION:**

**ViewController.m**

```
    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
        return [Model countKeys];
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [Model rowsInSection:section];
    }

    -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
// slightly crap code, this is initiated in viewDidLoad and is an array created by a method in Model.m. Only looks for keys and returns an array.
        return headerKeys[section];
    }
```

**Model.m**

```
+(NSArray *)headerKeys
{
    NSArray *headerKeys = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    headerKeys = [timerDictionary allKeys];
    NSLog(@"All keys: %@", headerKeys);
    return headerKeys;
}

+(NSArray *)customCellText
{
    NSArray *customCellText = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"dinnerItemText", @"dinnerDescriptionText", @"01:00", nil];
    return customCellText;
}

+(NSInteger)rowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionNumber
{
    NSArray *keyContent = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    keyContent = [timerDictionary objectForKey:dictionaryKeys[sectionNumber]];
    NSLog(@"current section[%i]: %i", sectionNumber, [keyContent count]);
    return [keyContent count];
}

+(NSArray *)cellText:(NSInteger)rowNumber
{
    // display all dictionary keys, dictionaryKeys[x] will give back the specific category
    dictionaryKeys = [timerDictionary allKeys];

    // displays contents of first key in dictionary
    NSArray *keyContent = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    keyContent = [timerDictionary objectForKey:dictionaryKeys[0]];

    // creates an array with all items within the selected key
    NSArray *keyItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:keyContent[rowNumber]];
    return keyItems;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the UITableViewController implementation?

Comment: Could post other data source methods? (i.e. `numberOfRowsInSection`)

Comment: What do you mean by `cell = customCell;`? What is customCell and can you show us the code where you are setting customCell?

Comment: Hi @danielrsmith - I've added the extra code beneath my question. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MikeD, I've added the other methods. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Fab1n , customCell is the identifier for my custom cell located within ViewController.xib - it's identifier is set in the Table View Cell property as you can see [here at the identifier stating MyCell](http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/SettingCellIdentifier.png)

Comment: you are overriding `cell` with a new object (whatever customCell is?!?!). Can you please show where you set `customCell`-variable? is it an instance variable? THIS IS IMPORTANT. Although I can tell you, overriding `cell` makes cell alloc init senseless and useless. You should delete `cell = customCell;`, otherwise it won't work...

Comment: Also you have to set a custom class for your cell nib and set your outlets there. Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath: don't cast the dequeueReusableCellWithCellIdentifier to `UITableViewCell`, but to your own class. Only then you can properly set the views and labels of your custom nib-cell!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say the following:

if you only do that:
`UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];`

prior to iOS 5 this doesn't guarantee you getting back a cell.  Prior to iOS5 you **have to** do the following:

NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I%d-%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    // assigns current row's labels
    NSArray * customCellText = [Model cellText:indexPath.row];
    dinnerItem.text = customCellText[0];
    dinnerDescription.text = customCellText[1];
    dinnerTime.text = customCellText[2];

    cell = customCell;
    return cell;
}
```

If you are on iOS5/6 these lines are not needed anymore:

```
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
```

**But** you **have to use** the following methods in the tableView setup:

```
registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:  (available in iOS6 and later)
registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: (available in iOS5 and later)
```

**Just hoping to solve your problem:**
Don't forget the lines [...](cell == nil)[...]

Comment: I can't vote up but I ended up creating a new xib with the customCell and using a similar implementation. Previously it was being shared with ViewController and the code above didn't quite work with it. You're right in stating that cell = customCell is incorrect as it overwrites it. I ended up doing `cell.dinnerItem.text = customCellText[0];
    cell.dinnerDescription.text = customCellText[1];
    cell.dinnerTime.text = customCellText[2]; return cell;`. I've come across a new issue here but I believe I can sort that out myself. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First, change your method to this! You need to check if the cell is `nil`:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        // assigns current row's labels
        NSArray * customCellText = [Model cellText:indexPath.row];
        dinnerItem.text = customCellText[0];
        dinnerDescription.text = customCellText[1];
        dinnerTime.text = customCellText[2];

        cell = customCell;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I've changed it to check if the cell is nil, and unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue (I tested this prior to submitting the question but wanted to keep it as simple as possible for people to help). I now know it needs to be in there so thanks for letting me know.

Comment: don't pack `// assigns current row's labels
        NSArray * customCellText = [Model cellText:indexPath.row];
        dinnerItem.text = customCellText[0];
        dinnerDescription.text = customCellText[1];
        dinnerTime.text = customCellText[2];

        cell = customCell;` in the if context!!! If you reuse, your cell isn't updated with the appropriate infos